# Disable a select element option based on a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey guys just been told that hide cannot be used cross browser for select element options.

So I am wondering how I can use disable for the following issue I am having.

This example is simplified, the actual code contains PHP loops and  MySQL to display the options and content.

Okay so first of all I have these two select elements:

```
<select class="form-control select-box">
    <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control select-box-model">
    <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
    <option value="C220">C220</option>
    <option value="X1">X1</option>
    <option value="X5">X5</option>
    <option value="XC90">XC90</option>
</select>
```

I then have these list:

```
<div class="makes BMW X1">
 <ul>
  <li>BMW</li>
  <li>X1</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="makes VOLVO XC90">
 <ul>
  <li>VOLVO</li>
  <li>XC90</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="makes MERCEDES C220">
 <ul>
  <li>MERCEDES</li>
  <li>C220</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="makes BMW X5">
 <ul>
  <li>BMW</li>
  <li>X1</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I am currently using this jQuery to hide the div with the class of 'makes' if the selected option doesn't match the div's class so for example 'BMW':

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make != 'make-any'){
      $('.makes').hide();
      $('.'+make).show();
      } else {
        $('.makes').show();
        }
    });
  });</script>
```

So as you can see I have a bit of a problem because the second select element with the class of "select-box-model" contains all of the models, I'd like to disable the options that aren't associated with the first select element option that has been selected.

For example the list containers contain the classes for the 'Make' and 'Model' of the each vehicle:

```
<div class="makes BMW X5">
```

So how can I disable the options that are not associated with that 'Make', for example if the user selects BMW for the first element I'd only like the 'Models' that are associated with the 'Make'.

Any examples would be great, thanks.

Comment: You are much better off having a separate select list for each make, instead of trying to combine all of the models for every make in one select. Then you could just show/hide by select list rather than option.

Comment: Or keep the option values in an array and populate the select from that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not completely certain that I have understood your question.

But I am assuming that you mean that if you select a car brand from select one `(form control)` the available models should be enabled in select two `select-box-model`. Once selecting the model, the accurate div needs to be shown?

If that is what you're trying to do your markup is not the best structure to achieve that.

Never the less, I made an example using your mark up:

jQuery:

```
$('.select-box-model').prop('disabled',true); 
$('.form-control').on('change',function(){
  $('.select-box-model').prop('disabled',false);
  if($(this).val() != 'make-any'){
    $('.makes').hide();           

    //check if the models drop down is used
    if($(this).hasClass('select-box-model')){
       //get selected value
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.'+ value).show();
        return false;
        }

    //get selected value
    var carBrand = $(this).val();
    $('.select-box-model option').prop('disabled',true);
    $('.'+ carBrand).find('li').each(function(){

    if($.trim(carBrand) != $.trim($(this).text())){
        $('.select-box-model option[value="'+ $(this).text() +'"]').attr("disabled", false);
       }
     });
   }
});
```

Here's a fiddle of that: http://jsfiddle.net/z59v56ec/

A neater solution to achieve this is using ajax to populate the models of the car brand.

But if you really want to do it your way, then the following logic is easier.

- Select one holds value of car brand
- Select two holds value of car brand and the text is the model
- Select one will enable the options in select two with the value of that car brand
- On select a model in select two the accurate divs would be shown according to the option text.

On a sidenote, be careful with your references. VOLVO is not the same as Volvo.

Just in case I completely missed the point - sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you are far better off creating multiple selects and toggling their display based upon your first select's selectedvalue.  Then, you create multiple divs and toggle their display based on your second select's selectedvalue.  That said, if you really want to attack this "dynamically", you're better off having two selects - and one unordered list - and clearing their contents and rewriting the html as you go:

```
<select class="form-control select-box" id="selectMake">
   <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
   <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
   <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control select-box-model" id="selectModel">
</select>

<ul id="ulCars">
</ul>

$("#selectMake").change(function(){
    $("#selectModel").empty();
    $("#ulCars").empty();

    switch ($(this).val()){
        case "BMW":
            $("#selectModel").append("<option>X1</option>").val("X1");
            $("#ulCars").append("<li>X1</li>");
        break;
    }
});
```

etc. etc., but you can easily clear lists and dropdowns - and then repopulate them.  But like I said, I'd go with multiple divs and toggling their display.